# Dynamically create index with mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a job that create new fields to my document, I want, at the end of this job, to create indexes to this fields. 
I tried

```
Model.index("field"=>-1)
```

and also

```
Mongoid::Sessions.default[:rating_prediction].ensureIndex
```

Without success

Is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Saying [`Model.index(:field => -1)`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Indexable/ClassMethods:index), more or less, just registers the existence of the index with `Model`, it doesn't actually create an index. You're looking for [`create_indexes`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Indexable/ClassMethods:create_indexes):

> `- (true) create_indexes`
>
> Send the actual index creation comments to the MongoDB driver

So you'd want to say:

```
Model.index(field: -1)
Model.create_indexes
```

You can also create them directly through Moped by calling [`create`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Indexes:create) on the collection's [`indexes`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Collection:indexes):

```
Mongoid::Sessions.default[:models].indexes.create(field: -1)
Model.collection.indexes.create(field: 1)
# or in newer versions:
Model.collection.indexes.create_one(field: 1)
```

`Mongoid::Sessions` has been renamed to `Mongoid::Clients` in newer versions so you might need to say:

```
Mongoid::Clients.default[:models].indexes.create(field: 1)
Model.collection.indexes.create(field: 1)
# or in even newer versions:
Model.collection.indexes.create_one(field: 1)
```

Thanks to [js_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2492795/js) and [mltsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79079/mltsy) for noting these changes.

Comment: For future reference `Mongoid::Sessions` is now called `Mongoid::Clients`,

Comment: @js_ Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The method is now called `create_one` 
so to dynamically create a unique compound index in Mongoid: `Model.collection.indexes.create_one({field: 1, another_field: 1}, {unique: true})`

Comment: @mltsy Like the updated version? I don't use MongoDB for anything anymore so it is hard for me to check.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I'm not sure when it changed - as far as I can tell, ever since Mongodb 2.0 it's been `create_one`: https://api.mongodb.com/ruby/2.0.6/Mongo/Index/View.html#create_one-instance_method