# mongoid create text index on all text fields on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoid, mongoid5

Can I create text index for all fields in ruby model like with this mongodb command:
`db.documents.createIndex({ "$**": "text" }, { name: "TextIndex" })`

Also can we somehow add number properties to index. I've tried like this but it doesn't

```
def fulltext_index
    attributes.except(:_rev, :_type, :doc_type).values.map{|e| e.class==String ? e.to_s : ""}.join(" ").strip + " " + sequence.to_s
end

index({ fulltext_index: "text"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the index you need as the second line in the following example:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'music') 
client[:bands].indexes.create_one( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Take a look to this link for further information:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/docs/tutorials/ruby-driver-indexing.txt

Answer (score 1):

In my case I need to open a rails console and run this:

for a model named Model

```
client = Mongoid.default_client[Model.collection_name]
client.indexes.create_one( { "$**" => "text" } )
```

For other custom idexes take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22570598/1900722)